# How to calculate energy required to rotate a cube?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, angular-velocity

I would like to apply force instantaneously at point $F$ in the given direction on cube $A$ and have it rotate around point $C$ to end up in the same position as cube $B$.

[image: Diagrams]

How would I calculate the energy required to bring the cube exactly to position $B$? Also, this is a 3D cube.

Comment: In an idealized scenario, the energy is just the difference in the gravitational potential energies of the two configurations. The formula for the gravitational potential energy is $PE = mgh$ where $m$ is the mass of the cube, $g = 9.8 m/s^2$ and $h$ is the height of the center of mass above the floor.

Comment: @user1379857  The question provides the external force which provides the torque. The mass of the cube isn't. If it is provided, your method is certainly simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Let r be the perpendicular distance from point F to the axis of rotation of the cube.
Then, torque applied on the cube is, $\tau$
  = r x F

Thus, work done in moving the cube from A to B is,
W = $\int_0^{π/4} \tau d\theta$
    = $\int_0^{π/4}$ r x F $d\theta$

Now, depending on whether F is a function of r or $\theta$, convert $d\theta$ to $dr$ or r in terms of $\theta$ and put that into the equation.
You will have the work done and thus, change in energy.